# sql procedure returns 1 but vb.net gets 0

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

I have stored procedure which seems to be working fine when executing directly from management studio, but when it comes o vb.net code i always get 0. Can anyone look at that and tell me what is missing here. I read documentation and seems that should work as expected however it is not somehow.

**stored procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsPhraseConnectedAlready]
        @PhraseId INT,
        @KatSubkatId INT,   
        @WordId INT,
        @SubsubkatId INT = NULL
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories TABLE(Id INT)
        DECLARE @temp_T_Html_WordCat_Phrase TABLE(FK_Phrase_ID INT)
        DECLARE @temp_T_Html_Phrase TABLE(Id INT, [Name] varchar(max))

        IF @SubsubkatId IS NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId And FK_Subsubkat_ID IS NULL;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN       
                INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId And FK_Subsubkat_ID = @SubsubkatId;
            END

        Declare @Id int;

        Select @Id = Id From @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories;

        INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_WordCat_Phrase(FK_Phrase_ID) SELECT FK_Phrase_ID FROM T_Html_WordCat_Phrase WHERE FK_Word_Categorie_ID = @Id;

        IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
            BEGIN
                Declare @FK_Phrase_ID int;
                --it makes no difference what you SELECT in an EXISTS sub-query as it is just syntactical sugar. (ie Nothing is actually selected.) SELECT * or SELECT 1 ...
                WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @temp_T_Html_WordCat_Phrase)     
                    BEGIN
                        Select Top 1 @FK_Phrase_ID = FK_Phrase_ID From @temp_T_Html_WordCat_Phrase;

                        INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Phrase(Id, [Name]) SELECT Id, [Name] FROM T_Html_Phrase WHERE Id = @FK_Phrase_ID;


                        IF (@PhraseId = @FK_Phrase_ID)
                                RETURN 1

                        Delete @temp_T_Html_WordCat_Phrase Where FK_Phrase_ID = @FK_Phrase_ID;      
                    END;
                END
        ELSE
                BEGIN
                    Delete @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories;
                    RETURN 0
                END

        RETURN 0  
    END
```

**This is my visual basic.net code below:**

```
Public Function IsPhraseConnectedAlready(phraseId As Integer, katsubkatid As Integer, wordid As Integer, subsubkatid As Integer?) As Integer
            Using con As New SqlConnection(_strcon)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("IsPhraseConnectedAlready", con)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhraseId", phraseId)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KatSubkatId", katsubkatid)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WordId", wordid)
                    If subsubkatid.HasValue Then  'check whether nullable field contain value
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubsubkatId", subsubkatid.Value)
                    Else
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubsubkatId", DBNull.Value)
                    End If
                    con.Open()
                    Dim i = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)

                    If i = 1 Then
                        Return True
                    ElseIf i = 0 Then
                        Return False
                    End If

                End Using
            End Using
        End Function
```

**Executed from ssms directly shows it reaches RETURN 1, however with same values passed from vb.net i am getting 0:**

[image]

**in vb.net working with same values:**

[image]

**seems the resolution was to do like this:**

instead of this:

```
RETURN 1 or RETURN 0
```

make it as:

```
SELECT 1 or SELECT 0
```

however to break execution when it reaches first select to add additional return after each SELECT.

Does anyone sees any issues with that? To me it works and wonder why just RETURN was not from vb.net

Comment: What does `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` return before you cast it?

Comment: @DanielShillcock without cast its Nothing

Comment: Please avoid copying images into your question. Double check connection strings, execute sproc in a query window within SSMS.

Comment: @DanielShillcock connection is fine, i executed sp in ssms as mentioned and it works resulting correct value

Comment: When i replaced RETURN 1 or RETURN 0  by SELECT 1 or SELECT 0 it works. I also had to add RETURN after each one because i want to break execution of sp when it reaches first SELECT. Can anyone tell me whether it's correct fix (works so far) also with this return

Comment: and does anyone know why just simple RETURN doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd.ExecuteScalar()` will execute the query, and return the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. However, you're not returning a column/row, you're just returning a value.

So, either convert `RETURN 1` to `SELECT 1` or else declare a return parameter in your VB.Net code like so:

```
...
Dim returnParameter As SqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int)
returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim i = CType(returnParameter.Value, Integer)
...
```

Comment: so my proposition in main post of mine in edit section is also correct?